# React-native - Sqlite - Android & iOS (both)

Tags: android, ios, sqlite, react-native

I have to create an android app with react-native. In this app while signup I should call a url to create user and get database in json formate. I desided that **Sqlite** is better for storing and reusing this data. But I dont know how to use **Sqlite db in react-native**. Please anyone can suggest me any **simple exmple of Sqlite with react-native which is use for android and iOS both.**

Comment: I must suggest to go with realm database.

Comment: how to use it? any simple exmple of realm db?

Comment: Please have a look to this tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/1464-realm-tutorial-getting-started